# Issue regarding test-rtc of web-rtc for Bandwidth test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having issue when using test-rtc of web-rtc.

When I launch the test on every browser (except chrome in Ubuntu) I get the following error: "(Throughput) Video bandwidth: Camera failure: 0x0. Cannot test bandwidth without a working  camera."

I console.log some code and I saw that from Chrome in Ubuntu (where it's working) the response parameters of the gotStats method for BandWidth tests is returning me a complete array. But for the other navigators this array is empty.

Could someone help me ?

If you need some screenshots or something else do not hesitate to ask.